# Sidebar menu issue in my site

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

How Do I Bring The Drop-down Menu In Front Of Other Graphic?
I just applied this CSS class on my side bar it works perfect and things are normal in full screen mode

```
.MYfixed {position:fixed;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

but when I collapsed my side bar the sidebar listing tag does not work perfectly.

what can I do?

Look at this image you can understand what I mean.

[image: my sidebar image]

Comment: post all of your code

Comment: anyone plz help me

Comment: I asked you to post all of your code.

Comment: i just below post my code

Answer (score 0):

Apply a higher z-index value to the HTML element that makes up the sidebar.

Watch for the z-index property of other elements in the body so you don't ruin other element's aesthetics, like modals.

Answer (score 0):

here is my css class

for fixed sidebar

```
.MYfixed { position:fixed; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

and for dropdown menu

```
.myFixed2 { position: absolute;z-index:1000;}
```

and my html code is:

```
<div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse MYfixed ">

   <ul class="page-sidebar-menu  page-header-fixed page-sidebar-menu-light" data-slide-speed="200" data-height="585" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="false">
                        <li class="sidebar-search-wrapper"></li>
                        <li class="nav-item start">
                            <a href="/Default.aspx" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                                <%--<i class="icon-home"></i>--%>
                                <img src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>assets/global/img/house.png" />
                                <span class="title">Home</span>
                                <span class="selected"></span>
                            </a>

                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item myFixed2">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle ">
                                <img src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>assets/global/img/admin.png" />
                                <span class="title">Administration</span>
                                <span class="selected"></span>
                                <span class="arrow open"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="nav-item ">
                                    <a href="/Administration/ModulesList.aspx" class="nav-link ">
                                        <span class="sidebarTitle">Modules List</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item  ">
                                    <a href="/Administration/UserSecurity.aspx" class="nav-link ">
                                        <span class="sidebarTitle">User Rights</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item  ">
                                    <a href="/Administration/AddUser.aspx" class="nav-link ">
                                        <span class="sidebarTitle">Add User</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

 </div>
```

Comment: i dont know how to use index value kindly help me